# Can't tilt MKMapkit map on Hybrid or Satellite view

Tags: ios, ios6, dictionary, mkmapview

I have a map in my iOS app, using MKMapKit. I am able to tilt the map (pitch) when it is on `MKMapTypeStandard`, but if I switch to `MKMapTypeSatellite` or `MKMapTypeHybrid`, I can no longer tilt. Tilt is available in the Maps App on all MKMapTypes. How can I enable it no matter what MKMapType?

```
-(void)layerSelect{
  mapIsStandard = !mapIsStandard;
  if(mapIsStandard){
    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
  } else {
    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
    _mapView.pitchEnabled = YES;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 7.0.2, Apple only allows developers to use pitch on the standard view, so no 3D pictures of buildings for us yet. However, if you go to a large city such as New York, it will show 3D gray outlines of buildings in standard view.

Comment: Thanks- where did you find this?

Comment: Assuming you can log into the Apple developer forums, here's the link: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/204001?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

When i asked the same question to apple. than here is the answer from apple. Its just for information.

Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS).

Based on your request Apple Developer Technical Support believes that your question is answered by the reference material linked below:

MKMapCamera Class Reference
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapCamera_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapCamera/pitch

Excerpt from URL above:
"If the map type is MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid, the pitch value is clamped to 0."

WWDC 2015 Session Video: What's New in MapKit 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=206

While a Technical Support Incident (TSI) was initially debited from your Apple Developer Program account for this request, we have assigned a replacement incident back to your account. However, if after reviewing this information you have further questions or persistent issues, please reply to this email and we will re-open this support inquiry, re-debiting a TSI accordingly.

Best Regards,

Developer Technical Support 
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations

what you say about this answer from apple..